# Can't make folders with some names in FreeNAS Samba shares

Tags: freebsd, samba, freenas

I have a FreeNAS box with 40 or so SMB shares. Mostly works no problem. Except for this one share where I can't create folder sometimes based on the name of the folder.

I noticed, because if I browse to the share within Windows and create a "New Folder", I just get a "permission denied" error (I assume this is because explorer makes a folder named "New Folder" first and then changes the name later). But if I browse to the directory from within my WLS instance, and create the folder named 'test' via `mkdir`, it creates it no problem.

Unless I try to make a folder 'New Folder' with `mkidr`.

This seems to be the case with a bunch of random folders, and from the FreeNAS box itself, I can create these folders no problem. The folders also certainly don't exist before hand, but if I create with FreeNAS, I'm able to delete them no problem from the places mounting these shares. But then not able to create them again.

This sounds like one of those problems where I'd just reboot the box, but around ~100 or so people are using it so I am trying to do this with as little down time as possible.

---

EDIT

This is still happening and I have no clue as to what's going on. Some test cases/examples that make no sense together

- Making a new folder in my Documents named "New Folder" and copying it
  to my share results in permission deined.
- Making a new folder called "New Folderx" in my Documents and copying
  it over works just fine. I can also rename this folder to anything
  except "New Folder"
- On the server itself, running `su -m brian -c 'mkdir "New Folder"'`
  works no problem, and from Windows, I can rename or delete this
  folder.
- "New Folder" is just an example folder that doesn't work, other folder names also randomly have these exact same issues
- This is only true for the root of the share, inside other folders, I don't have these issues

---

some sanity checks

```
$ getfacl .
# file: ../Share
# owner: root
# group: company
       group:super:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
            owner@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
            group@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow
```

```bsh
$ groups brian
brian super
```

```bsh
$ sharesec -v 'Share'
REVISION:1
CONTROL:SR|DP
OWNER:
GROUP:
ACL:S-1-5-21-4096896313-3432959665-639265334-1283:ALLOWED/0x0/FULL
ACL:S-1-5-21-4096896313-3432959665-639265334-1287:ALLOWED/0x0/FULL
```

```bsh
$ net groupmap list | grep super
super (S-1-5-21-4096896313-3432959665-639265334-1287) -> super
```

Comment: I have some questions for you.  What file system you are using?  What version os Samba is there?  What are the cpu/io stats for the FreeNas box when everyone is using it?  My guess is this issue is caused by Samba timeouts.

Comment: File system is zfs, smb is version 4.10.12, usage stats are quite low, this box isn't one that's constantly being hit

Comment: Do you get something like `NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`?  What version of zfs? (the 0.7.x?)

Comment: where would I be able to see an error message like `NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`? I'm trying to figure out how to find the zfs version now

Comment: For the samba, you maybe suffering from this bug -> https://bugzilla.samba.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14121.  The log file would be smb.log

Comment: Checking for zfs version just shows me a dash, and running all the other zfs version checking commands mentions something about being compiled with "feature flags"

Comment: As for zfs version that is my bad.  I'm using zfs on linux (ZoL) but you are using ZoF.  You need to run ` zpool get version <pool name>`.

Comment: yeah, that command just shows a dash `NAME  PROPERTY  VALUE    SOURCE
p1    version   -        default`

Comment: I see, then you are using feature flags (pool version "5000").  Then you should run `zpool get all <pool_name> | grep feature@`.  Anyways, I think you need to update your samba.

Comment: Can you upgrade individual components of a FreeNAS server, like smb?

Comment: So yes, I do get this error in the samba log (took a while to figure out where FreeNAS stores it's samba conf/logs) `filename_convert_internal: check_name failed for name New folder with NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: I'm far from being a FreeNAS expert, but from what I understand how it works you are not supposed to updage the packages, but since you are running FreeBSD under the hood you could use `pkg`, but you need to know what you are doing! You must be able to clean up the env - `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf.`

Comment: So that is definitely a samba problem.  From the message there could be a problem with the case of the directory naming.  For more I would need to have your `smb.conf` and also debug level 10 (use pastebin or such to poste longer posts)

Comment: So I have everything from the log when trying to create that folder https://pastebin.com/E4fLfWyQ, and the smb.conf https://pastebin.com/zjYZJxBN

Comment: Humour me please ... quote the share's `path` definition in your `smb.conf`, so `path = "/mnt/p2/Signature Patches"`

Comment: Nope, lol, that would have been interesting, "New Folder" throws same error, but "New Folder 2" works just fine, just for the heck of it I even opened the perms on the share to 777 and added `everyone@:rwxpDdaARWcCos:fd-----:allow` to the acl

Comment: No, he thinks in the configuration path:  `path = "/mnt/p2/Signature Patches"`

Comment: Yes I changed it to be quoted in my conf file but it didn't change the behavior

Comment: I've _just_ got to that point on a Samba configuration here and determined that, too. Thanks for checking though. (I'd always had it in my head that phrases containing a space had to be quoted in the `smb.conf`.)

Comment: Ok, I wanted to make sure you have mutual understanding.  I think I know where it crashes (the source code), but don't know the reason.  Does it fail on names without any space?

Comment: I don't think I've run into an example without a space in the name, no (although I don't think I have a lot of folders that created without spaces, they're almost exclusively names of customers)

Comment: My guess is that the issue has to do with the ACL (samba and zfs (zfsacl)) could you try adding these flags  to your share?  `nfs4:mode = special`  `nfs4:acedup = merge`   `nfs4:chown = yes`  (taken from here https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_zfsacl.8.html)

Comment: Those are already set except for the `nfs4: mode = special` one, but that one didn't change it either

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but this is also the only share I have where random new folders fail to inherit the permissions from the share folder correctly, maybe 1-2 times a day I have to manually set a folders permissions correctly (folders created by a service I have running on this machine)

Comment: First note the difference between `true` (your config) and `yes` at `nfs4:chown = yes` (according to the man).  Of course, that is **very** important.  That is the issue you are having at your Samba `check_reduced_name: couldn't get realpath for New folder`.  The issue is that the Samba tries to create the 'New Folder', which succeeds at the beginning, but then a last step when it tries to check the permissions for the "New Folder" it fails with a generic error which you can see at: `vfs.c` source.  If you fix the permission inheritance you probably solve your samba issue.

Comment: What fails is a function which to quote the source code: *This is called by every routine before it allows an operation on a filename. It does any final confirmation necessary to ensure that the filename is a valid one for the user to access.*

Comment: Ahh interesting, I didn't think about the inheritance problems being the source of it, it makes sense actually because it's the same problem for both folders. And the folder gets created with root only access, hmmm, somewhere else to look now

Comment: I'll post that as an answer, which probably is not worth the bounty as it does not solve the issue, but you know what to look for now.

Comment: Why the folder gets created with root only access?  Who is the owner?

Comment: Any chance that you are using links?

Comment: Nope, no links being created at all, there's a service that creates folders for new orders in our system that runs as root and sometimes (only in this one share/folder though, and never sub folders) they just don't inherit the permissions correctly

Comment: I see.  Please read the following *very* detailed document about ACLs perhaps it can help you - https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/methods-for-fine-tuning-samba-permissions.50739/

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the root cause is connected to the fact that Brian has to:

> This is also the only share I have where random new folders fail to inherit the permissions from the share folder correctly, maybe 1-2 times a day I have to manually set a folders permissions correctly (folders created by a service I have running on this machine)

The samba fails at the last moment when it tries to resolve already created filename at [`default:` branch (!resolved_name) check_reduced_name function](https://github.com/SpectraLogic/samba/blob/0791bb07ca4c356dab60e2a8223b1ebbc6ea0060/source3/smbd/vfs.c#L1196) (you can follow the code further).  The solution is connected to the resolution of the permission inheritance issue, where service has the same problems.

Comment: I'll come back to accept this for sure once I confirm that solving the inheritance issues is indeed the issue, but I've awarded the bounty anyway since you've been so helpful so far

Comment: Oof, I was going to try just making a new ZFS dataset and point the samba share there instead, but the FreeNAS UI won't let me with the error "Error getting pool data", maybe there's larger issues at play here

Comment: @BrianLeishman that sounds nasty, you definitely need to check your HW and zfs integrity.   Thank you for the reward.